# How to use int in array?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, int

i create a really simple coding and it got no errors but when it run, i cant put input in the 'age' side.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


struct baby
{
    char name[2][30];
    char sex[2][7];
    char birthday[2][12];
};

struct parents
{
    char nama[2][30];
    int age[2];
};

struct momdad
{
    struct parents father;
    struct parents mother;
};

struct momdad info;
struct baby newborn;

int main()
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter baby's name %d: ",i+1);
        gets(newborn.name[i]);

        printf("Enter baby's sex %d (Female/Male): ",i+1);
        gets(newborn.sex[i]);

        printf("Enter baby's birthday %d (dd/mm/yyyy): ",i+1);
        gets(newborn.birthday[i]);

        printf("Enter father's name %d: ",i+1);
        gets(info.father.nama[i]);
        printf("Enter father's age %d: ",i+1);
        gets(info.father.age[i]);

        printf("Enter mother's name %d: ",i+1);
        gets(info.mother.nama[i]);
        printf("Enter mother's age %d: ",i+1);
        gets(info.mother.age[i]);



    }

    printf("\n\n\tNEW BORN BABY IN KUANTAN HOSPITAL");
    printf("\n\n===============================================");

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
 {


        printf("\n\nBaby name: %s",newborn.name[i]);
        printf("\nSex: %s",newborn.sex[i]);
        printf("\nBirthday: %s",newborn.birthday[i]);
        printf("\n\nFather name: %s",info.father.nama[i]);
        printf("\nFather age: %s",info.father.age[i]);
        printf("\n\nMother name: %s",info.mother.nama[i]);
        printf("\nMother age: %s",info.mother.age[i]);
        printf("\n\n----------------------------------------------");
 }

    getch();
}
```

this is my declaration that i think is wrong but i dont know how.

```
int age[2];
```

and the input will be putting in here

```
printf("Enter father's age %d: ",i+1);
gets(info.father.age[i]);
```

n in here

```
printf("Enter mother's age %d: ",i+1);
gets(info.mother.age[i]);
```

i'm still new in programming *sorry for asking this simple question*

Comment: `gets()` is for reading strings, not integers. Take a look at `scanf()`, which can be used for reading different types.

Comment: @Barmar i've used scanf before but the same thing happen :(

Comment: @EricJablow of course it have two sexes, male and female. Does baby have only one sex?

Comment: @NadiaPerry `gets` shouldn't be used even for strings. How did you use `scanf`? Post the version of code using `scanf`.

Comment: @NadiaPerry, unless they are a hermaphrodite then they only have one, for instance a baby boy is a male, not female.

Comment: @Barmar heeyyyyy! I think its working now! THANKYOUUU! I need to put `fflush(stdin);` to makesure other things can run too! THANKYOU SO MUCHHHH!

Comment: @YuHao thankyouu! I get it now and you guys are really helpful! :')

Comment: Also only 1 birthday :)

Comment: @YuHao -- why not use gets() for strings?

Comment: @willus: [Why is the `gets' function is dangerous? Why should not be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-is-dangerous-why-should-not-be-used)

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Never use `gets()`. It cannot be used safely, and as of 2011 it's been removed from the language.

In a comment, you mention calling `fflush(stdin);`. The behavior of `fflush` is undefined for input streams. Some implementations define the behavior, but depending on that will make your program non-portable -- and you don't need it anyway.

The simplest way to read input data is to use `scanf()`, but that has some of its own problems. For example, if you use `scanf("%d", &n);` and type `123`, it will consume the `123` and leave anything following it (such as a newline) waiting to be read.

A better way to read input is to use `fgets` to read a line of text, then `sscanf` to parse the data from the input line. It re

Here's an example:

```
#define MAX_LEN 200
char line[MAX_LEN];
int num;

printf("Enter an integer: ");
fflush(stdout);

if (fgets(line, MAX_LEN, stdin) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error reading line\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (sscanf(line, "%d", &num) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error parsing integer from line\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
printf("The number is %d\n", num);
```

I call `fflush(stdout)` after the first `printf` to ensure that the prompt actually appears. `stdout` can be line-buffered, meaning that output won't appear until you've printed an entire line. The `fflush` isn't always necessary, but it's a good idea.

The `fgets` call reads a full line of input *or* `MAX_LEN` characters if the line is longer than that. (`gets` has no way to specify the maximum input size, so no matter how big your target array is, it can always read more and clobber random memory.) `fgets` returns a null pointer if there was a problem, and I check for that.

`sscanf` is similar to `scanf`, but it reads data from a string in memory, not from standard input. (There's also `fscanf`, which reads from a specified file.) It returns the number of items that it successfully scanned, so a value other than 1 would indicate an error.

I suggest reading the documentation for all these functions; I haven't covered everything they do. In fact, you should read the documentation for *any* standard library function you use.